# How to generate a temporary email for use in a web-application?

Tags: php, web-applications

**Example:** if I want to upload a video to some video service website (such as Youtube) by email, I can send a video to an email address (e.g `1234567890@upload.youtube.com`). The number is an upload code - It's a unique number and changes every time. Then Youtube will process and upload my video automatically.

How did they create the email address `1234567890@upload.youtube.com`, and how did they process an email message that a user has submitted?

I'm looking for the basic functionality behind this kind of web-application.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to create an e-mail service which associates given e-mails to accounts. Shouldn't be too hard, but I have no experience with processing received e-mails with php.

Comment: Creation by configuring MTA's (Exim, Postfix, the like) to pipe a certain emailaddress / emailaddresses to a script. Not that hard if you know the programs, and in this case, the user isn't even created, just a catch all email pipe to a process, and that process reads the `to` header & content. If you want to process the email with PHP look at `mailparse` in `PECL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done this, but I have a basic idea of how this is done.
There's a mail server on `upload.youtube.com` waiting for any email no matter who's the recipient.

Once it gets a message it will pipe it to a script which can parse it and get the recipient address (that's the uploader's unique identifier).

Then it will look in the email for the attachment and get MIME code, base64-decode it and then write it to a file on a disk.

Then it will add an entry in the database with the user's unique identifier and the link to that uploaded content.

Answer (score 1):

if you use cPanel you could use something like http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php to create the email accounts (use your own routines to generate the unique username etc) then you could use a script like http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/extracting-attachments-from-emails-with-php/ to get the attachments from the email.

Comment: you don't need to create a email address for each user. Just add some configuration to your mailserver in upload.example.com to catch all emails and use the "to" and/or "from" parameter to identify and authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out what I want.

All I have to do is handle with catch-all email on my web control panel. In my case, I just create a new subdomain and set a catch-all email option on that subdomain.

You can do all of above in Cpanel easily - just create a subdomain and selected a radio box `Pipe to a Program` and fill your application path. That's it!

Unfortunately, I'm using DirectAdmin. I have to do more complicated than Cpanel. It can handle with catch-all email as well, but I have to use wildcard dns for my subdomain record first.

In addition, I found this useful [article](http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/) about how to Pipe / Send Email to PHP Script. This article will show you every step including a PHP script for using with email piping.

Thank you for all answer. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's nice to know that you have achieved this.

I am here to introduce you to a script that can help you. The script  is  dealing with the dynamic email addresses with PHP. You can see the script at [github](https://github.com/harshitpeer/TMail-Lite)  and there is a premium version of this software you can see a demo [here](https://etempmail.net/). You can buy the script from [codecanyon](https://codecanyon.net/item/tmail-multi-domain-temporary-email-system/20177819).